# Spreadsheet.getRange() throws type error when trying to pass iterable as args

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using google AppScript to try and set the values of a range of cells iteratively, but consistently getting a type error when I try and reference the range. I suspect the error is my own, but I don't know what I should change to fix my implementation since the error seems to be wrong.
My implementation:

```
function extractLastBlockOfNumbers(sheet, column_to_split, numheaderrows = 1) {
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // insert a new column to hold the string
  sheet.insertColumnAfter(column_to_split);

  var listSplitColumnStrings;
  var lastSplitColumnString;

  // skip the header row(s)
  for (var i = numheaderrows; i < data.length; i++) {
    listSplitColumnStrings = data[i][column_to_split - 1 ].split('/');
    lastSplitColumnString = listSplitColumnStrings[listSplitColumnStrings.length - 1];
    sheet.getRange(i + 1, column_to_split + 1, 1, 1).setValue(lastSplitColumnString);
  }
  return;
}
```

Calling this function by passing it a the appropriate inputs ([Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet), int, and int) results in: `Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange.`

The column I'm trying to edit is obviously empty as I've just used the insertColumnAfter() function to create it.

I've tried referencing the range with "A1" notation, which works, but doing so is clunky because I have to convert the int referencing a column to a string and then concatenate with the row iterator.

EDIT: this ONLY happens when calling `setValues()`. If I try to use `getValues()` instead, `getRange()` is happy with the set of four int inputs.

Comment: Check the parameter `numheaderrows` passed to your function.  before `var data=` put the command `Logger.log("value = "+numheaderrows+ "type: "+(typeof numheaderrows))`.  I think you are passing a string to your function.

Comment: I've verified that my function call is passing an number, and I've also validated within the debugger that `getRange()` is being passed numbers as inputs.

Comment: Don't assume that this error is happening on `i=0`, it could be happening at the end of the loop. Trouble sheet the loop by inserting a line such as `Logger.log("i: "+i+", row = "+(i+1)+", range = "+(sheet.getRange(i + 1, column_to_split + 1, 1, 1)).getA1Notation())` as the first line of the loop. Also get a value for `data.length` so that you know how many instances are expected.